# Moving photos from one Photos library into another

Tags: photos.app, macos

We have two Photo libraries (one for my wife and one for me, different user accounts on one Mac, El Capitan). Now I would like to move most photos and videos from her Photos library into my Photos library.

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is to export the photos from her library and then copy them to /Users/[username]/Public/Drop Box. You can access these public folder from every other account on your computer and import the photos into the new library.

Answer (score 1):

Really, you can't.

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-10211

Short answer, if you like to edit, rate, or adjust your photos.  You have no way to migrate photos in libraries non-destructively without paying Apple for iCloud.

Comment: Or potentially by paying Fat Cat for PowerPhotos, which will copy most (but not all) metadata: https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/Help/copying%20limitations.html

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [PowerPhoto's](https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/) merging capability. It's not free though.

Answer (score 0):

Still no simple built in answer, but an additional app is [PhotosTakeout](https://photostakeout.com/Photos-Takeout-User-Guide1.pdf).

Using this tool, you can conveniently export the photos from the original Library. Then you would import them into the other Library. Then delete from the source Lib.

In truth, [PowerPhotos](https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/Docs/move_photos.html) will have to do the same operation. It cannot move them in one step, but can only copy them, leaving you to manually clean up by deleting the copied pix from the original Library. But that is one less step than with PhotosTakeout.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to merge libraries: iCloud photo library.

1. Move both libraries to the same user account (`/Users/Shared` is a good place to do this).
2. Set up Library A in iCloud Photo Library. You do this by making it the system library in Photos preferences.
3. Once the sync has finished, open Library B and make it the system library and turn on iCloud Photos.
4. You should now have both sets of photos in your iCloud library. You can disable iCloud Photos if you don't want to use it.