# How to manage Photos outside of ICloud

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app, photo-stream

The scenario is as follows:

- Using and paying for plenty of ICloud storage. Also paying for Office 365, therefore 1TB of storage  with Onedrive.
- Takes Photos on iPhone and iPad. Receives Photos via Whatsapp, and messages. Has Photos imported from older libraries.
- Wishes to separate into groups, pictures saved from Internet, pictures scanned using scanner, older Photos on hard drive.

Has one Photo library of about 75GB and 28k Photos.

I have suggested that referenced files feature be used for those that are not wanted in the main Photo stream as described [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/change-where-photos-and-videos-are-stored-pht1ed9b966d/mac).

The directories these referenced files are then stored in are backed up using Timemachine and iCloud Drive/OneDrive.

This means that on the iPad and iPhone the Photos that annoy the user are not visible, however they will remain manageable using the iMac's Photo's app so tasks like cropping the scans can be carried out easily.

It would be great really if Apple provided more granular management of Photos. Sorting into Albums is ok but doesn't allow Photos to be hidden from the main Photo stream. As far as I know there is no custom stream option, no labelling of Photos like is possible within the Finder application. Another option is to have multiple libraries, one for the Photos they like and one for each of the groupings that they don't want to view but need to manage. These other libraries could then be located in other directories that are backed up via the Cloud and not via the Photo stream... but switching between libraries is a pain and moving Photos between them will not only take some time (potentially more than 28000 Photos to go through) but involve exporting them, see [how to move photos between libraries](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229609/moving-photos-from-one-photos-library-into-another).

What is the most effective way to manage multiple groupings of Photos without the time-consuming process of have multiple Photo libraries?