# How do I Copy Photos from One Library to Another?

Tags: macos, photos

Simply exporting photos from one library to another in MacOS Photos will remove some of the features of the photos.

In MacOS Monterey, this feature has been added to Photos (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209528).  How has this been done  in previous MacOS versions?

I am looking for a solution that does not require purchasing software.  And I am willing to do manual file or folder manipulation if this is the only way to do it.  I do not have many photos to move.

Comment: Why not push things to iCloud and have that unify your libraries?

Comment: Thanks but I hoping to do this without uploading anything

Comment: Apple has invested the most engineering to solve your problem, then the two companies listed below as third party tools. Will be interesting to learn if anyone else has done the work on this (with fatcat focusing  roe on the merge function than the others IMO)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality wasn't available in Big Sur and older versions of macOS, apparently (See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229609/moving-photos-from-one-photos-library-into-another)). If you had a lot of photos, albums and folders to transfer, I'd suggest 3rd party software like [PowerPhoto](https://www.fatcatsoftware.com/powerphotos/) or [Photos Takeout](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1500714691) (The latter exports all metadata including keywords). Since you have only a few photos, export them (Select photos, then File > Export > Export N photos > (select options, e.g. Include title, keywords, caption) > Export. Then import into the other library.

Comment: I have saved so much of my time with my purchase of power photos. It’s amazing - great support. I don’t use keywords much so I didn’t evaluate the other option but third party tools are needed for this IMO.

Comment: My understanding is that this will not preserve the photo features.

Comment: Richard, which features won't be preserved? (Apart from Faces)

Comment: The Live preview for example.  Or the high resolution format.